# Compact connected complex/holomorphic manifold that embeds in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

> If $i : M \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a holomorphic map, then each coordinate function on $\mathbb{C}^n$ restricts to a global holomorphic function on the image. In particular, there is no holomorphic analogue of the Whitney embedding theorem; the only connected, compact holomorphic manifold that embeds holomorphically in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a point.

Could someone here explain this passage to me? I know the maximum principle that states that every holomorphic function on a connected, compact holomorphic manifold  is constant, but I'm not sure how it applies here? What is meant by each coordinate function on $\mathbb{C}^n$ restricting to a global holomorphic function on the image?

Comment: The terminology "restricts" is illiterate. Instead, you **compose** a coordinate function with $i$. Do you understand the passage now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. So if we have a connected compact holomorphic embedding $i : M \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is this saying that the coordinate representation of $i$ is constant in any holomorphic chart? A coordinate function would be a map $p_j : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $p_j(z_1,\dots,z_n) = z_j$ so the composition would be a a map $p_j \circ i : M \to \mathbb{C}$ and now what does it mean for this to be a global holomorphic function on the image? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Do you know what a holomorphic function on a complex manifold is? Do you know what a composition of maps is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M\subset \Bbb C^n$ is a compact submanifold, then the injection map $\iota\colon M \to \Bbb C^n$ is holomorphic by definition.
For $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, the coordinate map $z^j \colon \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C$ is holomorphic.
Therefore, the composition map $f^j = z^j\circ \iota \colon M \to \Bbb C^n$ is holomorphic.

The maximum principle implies that $f^j$ is constant whenever $M$ is compact.
In this case, the image of $\iota \colon M \to \Bbb C^n$ is constant, that is, a point.
Since $\iota$ is an embedding, it is in particular a bijection, and $M$ is a point.